# Validation with Laravel 4 and parsley.js

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-4, parsley.js

I want to evaluate forms built by Laravel on clientside with parsley .js.
But when I hit Submit no validation is made.

** in 'view.blade.php**

```
{{Form::open(array('action' => 'PositionController@createPosition', 'method' => 'post','files'=>true,'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data','parsley-validate' => 'true'))}}
  {{Form::text('position',NULL,array('parsley-required' => 'true', 'parsley-type' => 'number'))}}
  {{Form::submit('Hinzufügen',array('class' => 'blue'))}}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

** Output **

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/positions" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" parsley-validate="true">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="1234">
    <input parsley-required="true" parsley-type="number" name="position" type="text">
    <input class="blue" type="submit" value="Hinzuf&uuml;gen">
</form>
```

> Laravel Version: 4.1
>   Parsley Version: 1.2.3

**Update**

It seems to work, if I replace the form form builder code with a hardcoded HTML-Form. So I looked around the [docs](http://parsleyjs.org/documentation.html) and found:

```
$( '#form' ).parsley();
```

> Bind Parsley to a form (Useful if your form is dynamically rendered.)

But after adding '#parsleyForm' and the JavaScript binding to my site still nothing happens

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#parsleyForm').parsley();
        });
```

Any suggestions how I can use the Form Builder and Parsley?

Comment: Stupid question, you have the right path to the parsely.js file and it's being loaded correctly?  Also, try using just `parsley-validate` without setting it to true on `Form::open()`

Comment: Why stupid? Of course parsley is loaded correctly. Removing ="true"does not change anything.

Comment: I wasn't implying your question was stupid, I was implying I had a stupid question I wanted to ask to make sure things were being loaded. Sorry for coming off that way.

Comment: You only need `$('#parsleyForm').parsley();` if you don't/can't specify `parsley-validate="true"` on the `<form>`. Also, you do generate the form with `id="parsleyForm"`, yes?

Comment: Yes, I added the ID to test if it works with JavaScript.

Comment: You only need to use the `$( '#form' ).parsley();` functionality if your form/page is manipulated by javascript. I don't know **Laravel** but if it generates a static page, you should be able to use `parsley-validate="true"` on the `<form>`. It's a bit hard to see what could be going wrong. Can you post the whole (exactly as presented to the browser) page here, or to a jsfiddle or gist.github.com?

Comment: After looking at the code over and over again I decided to switch to backend validation with [Ardent](https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent) which works quite well. Thus all my Input forms changed and I have currently no time to restore the state with parsley. :/ Potentially I will test Parsley again on a later project state. Thanks for your efforts! :)

Comment: I am having the same issue and would like to continue using Blade's Form Builder. May have to drop parsley if it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/w54Q6/

With no changes, only specifying `jquery` and `parsley` as resources.

So, as @user3158900  has said, you probably haven't set up your paths to jquery and parsley correctly.